# Solution architecture Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, architecture

I am working with a third party vendor who I asked to provide me the events generated by a website

The vendor proposed to stream the events using Kafka ... why not...

On my side (the client) I am running a 100% MSSQL/Windows production environment and internal business want to have kpi and dashboard on website activities

Now the question - what would be the architecture to support a PoC so I can manage the inputs on one hand and create datamarts to deliver business needs?

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean by "events from website". Your Kafka producers are typically server side components, as you make API requests, you'd put Kafka producing events between those requests and your databases calls. I would be surprised if any third-party would just be able to do that immediately

Maybe you're looking for something like https://divolte.io/

You can also use CDC products to stream events out of your database

Comment: Sorry for not being clear; I am still discovering bits and pieces the marketing discussed with the third party.

Comment: Hi, here are some clarifications: the third party vendor (TPV) is hosting a website similar to a gaming website. From my customer perspective the log in (identification is mandatory) and play, purchase services, win, loose .... now, when I ask the TPV to share everything my customer did on the website (and in the future on the app), the TPV come with a Kafka stream solution (I guess the producer). I understand I need to build a consumer. And what next? Is the consumer able to populate a DAtabase or should I start thinking about hive, hbase, Hadoop ... thanks

Comment: Again, not clear how this website is able to send you that data. Especially if it's going to be securely communicated to your own Kafka cluster (or are they also hosting that?) And you can use a consumer to do anything. Confluent offers HDFS, S3, and JDBC connectors. Or you can use other hosted warehouse solutions like BigQuery or Snowflake

Comment: Hi onecricketeer’s - thanks for reverting. Very much appreciate. They are not hosting our Kafka cluster. The key of this exchange is may be to go bag to the initial requirements “how to collect in real time data coming from our website” hosted by third party and not in our network infrastructure “... may be Kafka is not the appropriate solution. How would you do it?

Comment: If data is generated by a website, JSON-RPC, SSE, or websockets are fairly standard. Kafka is not

Answer (score 1):

The architecture could be like this. The app streams event to Kafka. You can write a service to read the data from Kafka, do transformation and write to Database. You can then build Dashboard on top of DB.

Alternatively, you can populate indexes in Elastic Search and build Kibana dashboard as well.

Comment: Thanks Vikram! Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use `Lambda` architecture to cater both Real-time and Batch processing needs:

**Architecture:**

[image]

> Lambda architecture is designed to handle massive quantities of data by taking advantage of both batch and stream-processing methods.
>
> This architecture attempts to balance latency, throughput, and fault-tolerance by using batch processing to provide comprehensive and accurate views of batch data, while simultaneously using real-time stream processing to provide views of online data.

**Another Solution:**
[image]

Comment: I have added a possible solution. If this is not the solution you are looking for, please let me know, so that I will delete this post !

Comment: Hi sousmendra, any proposal is very much welcome at this stage as I do not feel limited by the proposition of my vendor. Thanks !

Comment: @lucTiber: added one more option using Hadoop stack !

Comment: Flume is kinda old. Nifi or Kafka Connect are more modern ways of getting the same goal